# Why does VS sort XML class childs alphabetical, and how to avoid that?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I've wrote a .cs file in a predefined structure to read in a specific type of XML files. That file has a lot more classes underneath. Round about 67 at this time.

[image]

This is my code to read in the .tcx files which are XML files.

```
        ModelData _xmlConfigData = new ModelData();
        XmlSerializer _xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ModelData));

        try
        {
            using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(xmlFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                _xmlConfigData = (ModelData)_xmlSerializer.Deserialize(filestream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong XML structure read in. Please select another XML file:" + ex);
            _xmlConfigData = null;
        }
        InvokeExtension.CreateListboxEntry(InvokeExtension.INFO + "TCX read successful", _lBox);
        InvokeExtension.SetProgressbarValue(1000, _pBar);
```

There are no errors at reading the hundreds of thousands of lines. But, if I look at my class object (at debugging) the subclasses are listed alphabetically sorted. The only thing I do is to read the .tcx into a ModelData-class-object and write it out to a new file.
This is my writer code:
[image]

After writing the new file the XML structure looks perfect, but **some of the child elements are now sorted in other direction compared to the original file. This is causing problems. I don't know why and how to prevent that sorting of the child nodes.** In my opinion it doens't matter in which sequence the child nodes are in an XML file.

Comment: You have to use the  `[XmlElement]` attribute with the [`XmlElementAttribute.Order`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlElementAttribute_Order) property for *every* element.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try. Thank u

Comment: Thank you Matt, your information solved my issue. Please, write it as an answer of this question to earn some reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netcore-3.1) will write out all the elements in alphabetical order.

You can change this by decorating *all* the elements with an [`[XmlElement]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=netcore-3.1), specifying an index value for that attribute's [`XmlElementAttribute.Order`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlElementAttribute_Order) property.

Note that once you choose to do this for one element, you must do it for *all* elements.